# Inline CSS is not working when referenced from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I feel as though this should work. I'm creating a variable in javascript and referencing it in the same file. Can someone explain why this is not working and then show how I can achieve my intended result? I feel as though I'm missing something obvious.

*edit: I forgot to mention that it is important that I use a javascript variable as my color. Sorry.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body style="background-color:color;">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var color = #555555;
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: That just does not work. Browsers don't work that way.

Comment: HTML doesn't parse JS variables, you'd have to do it all through JS

Comment: Is there anything I can do to use a javascript variable as a color?

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: @AndyHolmes You're the best! Thanks

Comment: @Zanolon no problem, please mark as accepted when you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example of use isn't how browsers work. If you wanted to achieve your example properly you could try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var color = '#555555'
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8dgoddw8/ - shows it working

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use this on your javascript:

```
  var color = '#555555';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

Comment: @JeremyThille "It's the exact same answer as the other one" might have been a giveaway.

Comment: Uuuuuuh... And except `<script type="text/javascript">`, what's different? Anyway, silent downvotes are always a pain.